# How do I show that I can work in a team environment without telling stories?

Tags: team, applications

I am filling out a form that says:

> Your claim for a position should provide brief details of your
>   experience and skills under the below headings

One heading is "Working in a Team Environment". If someone asked me about working in a team environment in an interview, I'd try to demonstrate desirable qualities by telling stories where I either demonstrated the quality or I learned the importance of it. However, the question, as stated, doesn't seem to allow for this. I suppose I could list a few group assignments or competitions where we scored well. I could also try to mention team projects at work, but I don't really know what I'd say other than that we completed the project or to just generally say that I have experience working in a team environment at this job.

Is there a better method to demonstrate that I can work in a team environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a generic question that they pose to every applicant for every position. But I am going to assume that it is important for the position you are applying for.

The job might be a part of a team. You might be the only person of your type on the project team. Or the team could be only a group of people all with the same job type. For example one graphic artist on a 10 person project team; or one of 10 graphic artists supporting company headquarters.

Try to think of examples of situations where you have worked in those situations. You don't want to tell stories. But you want to be able to describe the teams you were involved with.

> I was the only widget maker on the factory upgrade team. I had to work with the health and safety team to design an new workflow to reduce repetitive motion injuries. By working with the mechanical engineering office we were able to increase output by 10%, decrease cost by 2%, and reduce injuries by 50%. I also had to interface with the robotics team to reduce the number of steps in the critical part of the process.
>
> I worked with the other widget makers on my shift to remake the QA process to increase the likelihood of catching problems with the new widget. When the new model was being designed the group I worked with was responsible for testing the new procedures. After it was in production, I was one of the tiger team members to demonstrate the new procedure at the other plants.

Answer (score 1):

If they're asking you that they want to know:

- the workflow in your team and **your participation**. What did you exactly do, how did you *helped* the team?
- did your team ever encountered **difficult moments**? How did you *helped*?
- did you ever had to work **on your own** on something? How did you handled? (yes, this can tell something about your teamwork abilities)
- how is your team **relaxing**/enjoying work? Did you guys have some common hobbies?
- how do you **react** when most of your colleagues are in vacation and a big chuck of work is suddenly needed to be done ASAP?

Focus on those parts an you won't make a mistake :) I've bolded the key aspects.